# Elastic search query equivalent of IN clause and OR combined

Tags: elasticsearch

Looking for an elastic search query which will do something like this pseudo code:

```
WHERE 
car in ('ford', 'bmw', 'mercedes')
or car field does not exist
```

So given the below documents as an input, it will return documents 1, 3 and 4 as the hits

```
{id: 1, car: 'ford'}
{id: 2, car: 'chevrolet'}
{id: 3, name: 'John'}
{id: 4, car: 'bmw'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean query to combine [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) and [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html). The equivalent search query will be

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "terms": {
                "car": [
                  "ford",
                  "mercedes",
                  "bmw"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "car"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The search result is

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65782573",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1,
          "car": "ford"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65782573",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 4,
          "car": "bmw"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65782573",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "John"
        }
      }
    ]
```